# How can label nodes be conditionally inserted into TikZ paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border = 10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {align = center}]
    \newcounter {lfpnode}
    \coordinate (LFP) at (0,0);
    \newcommand {\drawaline} [3] {
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}
            {\def\tdsdabovespec{}}
            {\def\tdsdabovespec{node[above] \unexpanded{{#2}}}}

        \coordinate (LFPS) at ($(LFP) - (0,{#1})$);
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}} {
            \def\tdsdnewLFP{LFPS}
            \def\tdsdbelowspec{}
        }{
            \edef\tdsdlfpnode{LFPN\arabic{lfpnode}}
            \def\tdsdnewLFP{0,0 |- \tdsdlfpnode.south}
            \def\tdsdbelowspec{node[below] (\tdsdlfpnode) \unexpanded{{#3}}}
        }

            % this doesn't work
            \def\tdsddataflowspec{[blue] (0,0 |- LFPS) -> \tdsdabovespec \tdsdbelowspec (5,0 |- LFPS)}
            \expandafter\draw\tdsddataflowspec;

            % neither does this, although I didn't expect it to
            \draw [blue] (0,0 |- LFPS) -> \tdsdabovespec \tdsdbelowspec (5,0 |- LFPS);

        \coordinate (LFP) at (\tdsdnewLFP);
        \stepcounter{lfpnode}
    }

    \newcommand {\drawalineone} [1] {
        \def\tdsdnewLFP{LFPS}
        \coordinate (LFPS) at ($(LFP) - (0,{#1})$);

            \draw [blue] (0,0 |- LFPS) -> node[above] {ABOVE1-1\\ABOVE1-2} (5,0 |- LFPS);

        \coordinate (LFP) at (\tdsdnewLFP);
        \stepcounter{lfpnode}
    }

    \newcommand {\drawalinetwo} [1] {
        \coordinate (LFPS) at ($(LFP) - (0,{#1})$);
        \edef\tdsdlfpnode{LFPN\arabic{lfpnode}}
        \def\tdsdnewLFP{0,0 |- \tdsdlfpnode.south}

            \draw [blue] (0,0 |- LFPS) -> node[above] {ABOVE2-1} node[below]
                (\tdsdlfpnode) {BELOW2-1} (5,0 |- LFPS);

        \coordinate (LFP) at (\tdsdnewLFP);
        \stepcounter{lfpnode}
    }

    \newcommand {\drawalinethree} [1] {
        \coordinate (LFPS) at ($(LFP) - (0,{#1})$);
        \edef\tdsdlfpnode{LFPN\arabic{lfpnode}}
        \def\tdsdnewLFP{0,0 |- \tdsdlfpnode.south}

            \draw [blue] (0,0 |- LFPS) -> node[below] (\tdsdlfpnode) {BELOW3-1\\BELOW3-2} (5,0 |- LFPS);

        \coordinate (LFP) at (\tdsdnewLFP);
        \stepcounter{lfpnode}
    }

    % The following causes errors aplenty:
    %    "Cannot parse this coordinate."
    %    "A node must have a (possibly empty) label text."
    %    "Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?"
    % \drawaline{0}     {ABOVE1-1\\ABOVE1-2} {}
    % \drawaline{1.3cm} {ABOVE2-1} {BELOW2-1}
    % \drawaline{1cm}   {} {BELOW3-1\\BELOW3-2}

    % Works!
    \drawalineone{0}
    \drawalinetwo{1.3cm}
    \drawalinethree{1cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The general idea is simple: `\drawaline` draws a line and accepts three arguments. If the second argument is nonempty, a label appears above the line. If the third argument is nonempty, a label appears below the line.

The vertical spacing of the lines is such that a space defined by the first argument appears between the line currently being rendered and the lowest point (including label, if present) of the previously-rendered line. This isn't crucial for the MWE, but I've included it since it's how the code is used in the original context, and it might conceivably affect which fixes are possible.

The `\drawalineone`, `\drawalinetwo`, and `\drawalinethree` macros are hard-coded versions of `\drawaline`. They function as expected. The actual `\drawaline` macro does not. Note that neither of the approaches used in `\drawaline` works when `\unexpanded{{#2}}` (and likewise for `#3`) are replaced by simply `{#2}`, or by `\begingroup #2\endgroup`. In short, I don't know how to get TikZ to recognize the content following `\draw` as a parseable TikZ path spec.

Finally, please note that the `\drawaline` macro *must* accept multi-line labels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the `->` path command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your objective --- but if I understood correctly your description, I tried to simplify it.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\drawline[3]{
    % the position of the line is #1 below the previous line
    % it is not accounting for the (not typeset yet) above box
    \path (lastline) ++(0,{-(#1)}) coordinate(thisline);
    % draw the line and mark midway
    \draw (thisline) -- ++(5,0) coordinate[pos=0.5](midline);
    % if we have the box above, draw it
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\node[above, align=center] at (midline) {#2};}
    % if we have the box below, type it. Either case, re-set
    % the (lastline) position accordingly
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}
        {\coordinate(lastline) at (thisline);}
        {\node[below, align=center](tmp) at (midline) {#3};
        \coordinate(lastline) at (thisline|-tmp.south);}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \coordinate (lastline) at (0,0);
    \drawline{0}{Only \\ above}{}
    \drawline{2}{Either \\ above}{Or \\ below}
    \drawline{1}{}{Only \\ below}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Taking into account the size of the text block above, in order to specify the distance between the texts instead of the lines, will be a bit more complex, but not impossible...

Comment: I wasn't aware of the inline `coordinate` syntax for recording coordinates. This works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the complete solution, but perhaps a direction to go. I tried to use one of your code examples and enhanced it a bit:

```
    \newcommand {\drawalinetwo} [3] {
    \coordinate (LFPS) at ($(LFP) - (0,{#1})$);
    \edef\tdsdlfpnode{LFPN\arabic{lfpnode}}
    \def\tdsdnewLFP{0,0 |- \tdsdlfpnode.south}

        \draw [blue] (0,0 |- LFPS) -- node[above] {#2} node[below]
            (\tdsdlfpnode) {#3} (5,0 |- LFPS);

    \coordinate (LFP) at (\tdsdnewLFP);
    \stepcounter{lfpnode}
}
```

With the commands

```
\drawalinetwo{1cm}{}{BELOW2-1}
\drawalinetwo{1cm}{ABOVE2-1}{}
\drawalinetwo{1cm}{ABOVE2-1}{BELOW2-1}
```

I get this:

[image]